# Ripple effect for pre Android Lollipop

Tags: android, animation, ripple

First off I'd like to ask why pre Lollipop don't have the ripple effect, 
Then is there any library, hack or something to use to implement ripple on pre Lollipop. I have tried alot of things, closest I get is app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect. There are some more cool libraries at http://android-arsenal.com . Try those out.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The Library is for android studio, I need for eclipse, any suggestions?